# Displaying MySQL data on web page

Tags: php, html, foreach

My data is successfully displaying on the web page using the foreach loop however, I want to apply a unique image and color to each box that contains data from the database. This will be prevented by the foreach loop which will iterate the boxes to have the same color and image. I feel arrays would be useful for enabling me to have boxes with different images and color, but I wanted to know how to go about doing so.

```
<?php

//check connection

if(!$conn){
    echo 'connection error: ' . mysqli_connect_error();
}

//write  query for all pizzas

$sql = 'SELECT * FROM pizzas ORDER BY created_at';

//Make query and get result

$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

//fecth the resulting rows as an array

$pizzas = mysqli_fetch_all($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);

//free result from memory

mysqli_free_result($result);

//close connnection

mysqli_close($conn);
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>
        PHP File
        </title>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    </head>

    <body>

        <h4 class="text-center">Project Archives</h4>

        <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <?php foreach($pizzas as $pizza){ ?>            
            <div class="col-sm-4 case-studies" data-modal="modal5">


                <div class="intro-block five">
                    <h3 class="case-study title"><?php echo htmlspecialchars($pizza['title']);?></h3>
                    <p class="case-study summary"><?php echo htmlspecialchars($pizza['case_text']);?></p>
                    <a class="brand-text" href="#">More info</a>            
                </div>

            </div>

            <?php } ?>

            </div>

        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What about using conditions? Check whatever condition you want, then apply the color as needed

Comment: @CarlBinalla Still fairly new to PHP and MySQL so still unsure of what would be the best way to apply separate designs to each of the outputted data

Comment: Like I said, use [conditions](https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.if.php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways that you might accomplish this task, perhaps the following might be of interest as you did mention an `array` ~ but it is unclear how you intend to apply the colour and image - so I guessed.

This approach is limited in that you need to define the array of colours / images before iterating through the recordset and, as it is currently, would fail when the end of the array is reached if there were more records.

```
<?php

    $sql = 'SELECT * FROM pizzas ORDER BY created_at';
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    $pizzas = mysqli_fetch_all($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
    mysqli_free_result($result);
    mysqli_close($conn);



    $styles=array(
        ['colour'=>'red','image'=>'/images/pizza/p1.jpg'],
        ['colour'=>'yellow','image'=>'/images/pizza/p2.jpg'],
        ['colour'=>'green','image'=>'/images/pizza/p3.jpg'],
        ['colour'=>'blue','image'=>'/images/pizza/p4.jpg'],
        ['colour'=>'brown','image'=>'/images/pizza/p5.jpg'],
        ['colour'=>'pink','image'=>'/images/pizza/p6.jpg'],
        ['colour'=>'orange','image'=>'/images/pizza/p8.jpg']/* etc */
    );
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>PHP File</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>

        <h4 class="text-center">Project Archives</h4>

        <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <?php 

            foreach( $pizzas as $index => $pizza ){ 
                $style=$styles[ $index ];
                $colour=$style['colour'];
                $image=$style['image'];


            ?>          
            <div class="col-sm-4 case-studies" data-modal="modal5" style="color:<?php echo $colour;?>">

                <img src='<?php echo $image;?>' />

                <div class="intro-block five">
                    <h3 class="case-study title"><?php echo htmlspecialchars($pizza['title']);?></h3>
                    <p class="case-study summary"><?php echo htmlspecialchars($pizza['case_text']);?></p>
                    <a class="brand-text" href="#">More info</a>            
                </div>

            </div>

            <?php } ?>

            </div>

        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

As mention above. If the recordset still has further records but there are no more items in the $styles array an error will occur. You could, at that point re-use the $styles array in some manner, perhaps like this:

```
$index=0;
foreach( $pizzas as $pizza ){

    if( $index > count( $styles ) - 1 ) {
        shuffle( $styles );
        $index=0;
    }

    $style=$styles[ $index ];
    $colour=$style['colour'];
    $image=$style['image'];                 

    /* etc as before ... */



    /* content */


    /* content */

    $index++;
}//end loop
```